# Google Maps API. infoWindow with next and back buttons to cycle through the information for markers in the same position

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have markers being placed onto my Google map from an XML file. However some markers will be in the exact position (latitude and longitude) I was wondering if there was away to click on the top marker, open up the infoWindow and have next button to cycle through the xml data for each markers that is in the same position, I have no idea how to go about this:

This is my current js, that places the markers and creates the infoWindow

```
var customIcons = {
    been: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
    },
    going: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
    }
};

function load() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        mapTypeControl: false
    });
    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        infoWindow.close();
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17); 
        }
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
    downloadUrl("markers.php", function (data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var customer = markers[i].getAttribute("customer");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var visit_date = markers[i].getAttribute("visit_date");
            var comments = markers[i].getAttribute("comments");
            var image = markers[i].getAttribute("image");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var html = "<div class=\"information\"><div class=\"thumb\"></div><span class=\"name\">" + name + "</span><span class=\"customer\"><b>Customer Name:</b> " + customer + "</span><br /><b>Address:</b> " + address + "<br /><span class=\"date\"><b>Visit Date:</b> " + visit_date + "</span><br /><span class=\"comments\"><img src=\"images/oq.png\" />" + comments + "<img src=\"images/cq.png\" /></span><img src=\'" + image + "'\" class=\"image\" /><div>";
            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon,
                shadow: icon.shadow
            });
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
    });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".date-pick").glDatePicker({
        onChange: function (target, newDate) {
            target.val(
            newDate.getFullYear() + "/" + (newDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + newDate.getDate());
        }
    });
});
```

Any suggestions? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
// these variables are global variables
 var infoWindow;
 var map;
// Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
    downloadUrl("markers.php", function (data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var customer = markers[i].getAttribute("customer");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var visit_date = markers[i].getAttribute("visit_date");
            var comments = markers[i].getAttribute("comments");
            var image = markers[i].getAttribute("image");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
           markers[i].getAttribute("lat"),markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
            var html = "<div class=\"information\"><div class=\"thumb\"></div><span class=\"name\">" + name + "</span><span class=\"customer\"><b>Customer Name:</b> " + customer + "</span><br /><b>Address:</b> " + address + "<br /><span class=\"date\"><b>Visit Date:</b> " + visit_date + "</span><br /><span class=\"comments\"><img src=\"images/oq.png\" />" + comments + "<img src=\"images/cq.png\" /></span><img src=\'" + image + "'\" class=\"image\" /><div>";
            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon,
                shadow: icon.shadow
            });
            bindInfoWindow(marker,   html);
        }
    });
}


function bindInfoWindow(marker,  html) {

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {


             if (infowindow) {

                infowindow.close();
            }

      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                        {
                            content: html                             

                        });

    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, Not working, but I think this would just close the infoWindow if there was already one open? and then create a new one and adding back the previous HTML string? Cheers Andy

Comment: yes.. close the infowindow if it is exists and open it again.. your problem is that infowindow is opend but same place.?

Comment: Well I would have thought if there was 2 markers one on top of the other when you click the top marker the infoWindow for that marker only displays, not the one underneath? Or is it that when I select the top one, the maker underneath opens its infoWindow as well as the one on top?

Comment: can you check withour using parseFloat() function

Comment: getting map is not defined? iv placed latest code here: http://jsfiddle.net/devTh/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12566/discussion-between-ajfmedia-and-stay-hungry)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if any one is still looking for the answer for this question.
Here is my solution using carousel.

1. Add all your markers to a global variable
2. While binding info window check if marker overlaps any of the existing markers
3. If it overlaps, on the click of marker append the contents as carousel to the current marker
4. On close of the marker reset the content string to original  one

Here is the code sample

```
var markers = [];
var markerContentString = null;
function load() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    mapTypeControl: false
});
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    infoWindow.close();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);
    }
});

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
// Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
downloadUrl("markers.php", function (data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var customer = markers[i].getAttribute("customer");
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
        var visit_date = markers[i].getAttribute("visit_date");
        var comments = markers[i].getAttribute("comments");
        var image = markers[i].getAttribute("image");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var html = "<div class=\"information\"><div class=\"thumb\"></div><span class=\"name\">" + name + "</span><span class=\"customer\"><b>Customer Name:</b> " + customer + "</span><br /><b>Address:</b> " + address + "<br /><span class=\"date\"><b>Visit Date:</b> " + visit_date + "</span><br /><span class=\"comments\"><img src=\"images/oq.png\" />" + comments + "<img src=\"images/cq.png\" /></span><img src=\'" + image + "'\" class=\"image\" /><div>";
        var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow,
            _content: html //Add html content to _content
        });
        markers.push(marker); //Add markers to array
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
});
}
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
var overlappingMarkers = getOverlappingMarkers(marker); //Check if current marker overlps with any of the existing markers
if (overlappingMarkers.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < overlappingMarkers.length; i++) {
        overlappingMarkers[i].label = {
            text: overlappingMarkers.length,
            color: 'white'
        }; //Add count of marker at that ocation as label 
    }
}
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    markerContentString = html; //Save content string of maker to a global variable
    var appentedContentString = null;
    if (overlappingMarkers.length > 1) {
        appentedContentString = '<div class="slideshow-container">';
        for (var i = overlappingMarkers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var style = i === overlappingMarkers.length - 1 ? 'style="display:block;"' : "";
            appentedContentString += '<div class="mySlides fade" ' + style + '>' +
                overlappingMarkers[i]._content +
                '</div>';
        }
        appentedContentString += '<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>' +
            '<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<br>' +
            '<div style="text-align:center">';
        for (var i = 0; i < overlappingMarkers.length; i++) {
            var className = i === 0 ? "dot active" : "dot";
            var newSlide = i + 1;
            appentedContentString += '<span class="' + className + '" onclick="currentSlide(' + newSlide + ')"></span> ';
        }
        appentedContentString += '</div>';
    }
    var infoContent = appentedContentString == null ? markerContentString : appentedContentString;
    infowindow.setContent(infoContent);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    showSlides(1);

    //Resetting content on closing infowindow
    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
        imageInfo.content = markerContentString;
        markerContentString = null;
    });
});
}

function currentSlide(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function plusSlides(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
if (!slides || slides.length < 1) return;
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
}
if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

function getOverlappingMarkers(marker) {
var overlappingMarkers = [];
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i].getPosition().lat() == marker.getPosition().lat() &&
        markers[i].getPosition().lng() == marker.getPosition().lng()) {
        overlappingMarkers.push(markers[i]);
    }
}
return overlappingMarkers;
}
```

Now in the style section add the following

```
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .mySlides {
        display: none;
    }

    img {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    /* Slideshow container */
    .slideshow-container {
        max-width: 1000px;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
    }
    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev, .next {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 45%;
        width: auto;
        padding: 16px;
        margin-top: -22px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        transition: 0.6s ease;
        border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        user-select: none;
    }

    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
        right: 0;
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

        /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
        .prev:hover, .next:hover {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        }



    /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
    .dot {
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        margin: 0 2px;
        background-color: #bbb;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }

        .active, .dot:hover {
            background-color: #717171;
        }

    /* Fading animation */
    .fade {
        -webkit-animation-name: fade;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
        animation-name: fade;
        animation-duration: 1.5s;
    }
</style>
```